# check if number of days has passed since a date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am trying to check if a certain number of days has passed since a date and if it has then change the color of the grid row.
So if the date is 12/11/2016 and I want to check if 10 days has passed since that date.

```
if (dt.Date > dt.Date.AddDays(10))
{
     e.Item.Style.Add("background-color", "#C400F9");
     break;
}
```

So adding 10 days to the 12th would be the 22/11/2016 and since today is the 23/11/2016 that means 10 days has passed. But all rows in the grid are changing to the color. Do I need to add another if statement to compare the date + the days passed to today's date?

Comment: Have you posted relevant example? Condition `dt.Date > dt.Date.AddDays(10)` will never be met, so yor rows can't change color based on this condition. It's hard to say what's wrong in your *real* condition....

Comment: everyone mentioned the comparison issue, and I'm assuming that was just sample code because no rows will get the color and you are saying every row is getting it. Is `dt` a global date, or the date on the row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can relative time be calculated in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-can-relative-time-be-calculated-in-c)

Comment: @VDWWD Not at all related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you mean to use today's date? If so, that's `DateTime.Now`:

```
if (DateTime.Now > dt.Date.AddDays(10))
```

At the moment you are comparing `dt.Date` against same date plus 10 days - as others noted, this will never be met.

**Update.** As Tim suggests in comments, using `DateTime.Today` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Better use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now` here, otherwise midnight will return false but one second later you get true, both are same-day

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime d1;
DateTime d2;

if((d1 - d2).TotalDays == 10)
{
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your comparison. You're trying to figure out if `dt` is bigger than `dt` + 10. Obviously it will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison will never be true, it's like doing:

If (10 > 10 + 10)...

What you want to do is compare 10 days after the date with *today* using DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Date> dt.Date.AddDays(10).Date)
{
    e.Item.Style.Add("background-color", "#C400F9");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Date > dt.Date.AddDays(10))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this, Below X is date that you want to compare with(it may come form db or hardcoded date)

```
if (X > dt.Date.AddDays(10))
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("background-color", "#C400F9");
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code as the OP has in their question. Did you mean to edit it into something else?